# Use delegates in wcf service reference

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, delegates

I`v got a problem in my wcf service.

Here is my service interface class:

```
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISahandService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool uRunCommand(byte[] abyJson, ref byte[] abyData);

    [OperationContract]
    bool uFillSaatDic(ref List<DeviceInfo> liDev, ref string sErr);

    [OperationContract]
    void uSetDelegates(dlgDeviceConnectFunc uDeviceConnect, dlgServerBusyFunc uServerBusyFunc,
        dlgAminConnection uAminFunc, dlgFingerUI uFingerUI, dlgOnFinger uOnFinger);

    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}
```

and error is:

Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.

> c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\Test Client Projects\12.0\71e9b3ab-7556-4f8d-87c7-c8bae5868d3a\Client.cs(391,26) : error CS0644: 'SahandCL.dlgDeviceConnectFunc' cannot derive from special class 'System.MulticastDelegate'
>   c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\Test Client Projects\12.0\71e9b3ab-7556-4f8d-87c7-c8bae5868d3a\Client.cs(403,26) : error CS0644: 'SahandCL.dlgServerBusyFunc' cannot derive from special class 'System.MulticastDelegate'
>   c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\Test Client Projects\12.0\71e9b3ab-7556-4f8d-87c7-c8bae5868d3a\Client.cs(415,26) : error CS0644: 'SahandCL.dlgAminConnection' cannot derive from special class 'System.MulticastDelegate'
>   c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\Test Client Projects\12.0\71e9b3ab-7556-4f8d-87c7-c8bae5868d3a\Client.cs(427,26) : error CS0644: 'SahandCL.dlgFingerUI' cannot derive from special class 'System.MulticastDelegate'
>   c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\Test Client Projects\12.0\71e9b3ab-7556-4f8d-87c7-c8bae5868d3a\Client.cs(439,26) : error CS0644: 'SahandCL.dlgOnFinger' cannot derive from special class 'System.MulticastDelegate'

and the question is: How can i use delegates in my service reference?

Comment: WCF cannot serialize delegate types. Any types used in the contract must be serializable using the Data Contract serializer, or Xml Serializer.

Comment: i have a device that has some realtime events, i want to use it in service layer and ui can trigger that events, what can i do?

Comment: @HamidSOS, why don't you just have your client call an operation on the service that does what the delegate does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only known types are allowed while defining WCF contracts.